# Что сделать что бы Atom выводил результат на русском?

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, atom

Версия: python3
Редактор: Atom
Что нужно сделать что бы Атом отображал русский текст?
Пример кода:

```
print('Привет Мир!')
```

Но вывод происходит такой:

```
������ ���!
[Finished in 0.056s]
```

P.S.: Кодировка стоит UTF-8

Comment: Я думаю, что utf8 -- это у Вас кодировка текстового редактора атома, а не консоли, в которую вывод идёт. Значит, надо поменять кодировку или шрифт (возможно, её шрифт не поддерживает русский язык) самой консоли, правда, я не знаю, как, потому что атомом не пользуюсь. P.S. https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/214#issuecomment-172901760 -- похоже, может помочь. Или https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/214#issuecomment-418766763

Comment: Лучше я думаю использовать PyScripter

Comment: напиши print(u'Привет Мир!') и скажи какой результат

Comment: @Paweł не работает

Answer (score 2):

Я нашел ответ на собственный вопрос и хочу поставить точку раз и навсегда в этой теме. Проверял на многих системах это решение и на данный момент работает в 100% случаев.
Итак, для тех, кто до сих пор серфит инет в надежде найти решение этой проблемы, ниже я оставлю подробный путь.
Пример привожу на Windows 10: 
`Пуск` --> `Settings` --> `Время и язык` --> `Регион` --> `Дополнительные параметры`(справа) --> `Региональные стандарты` --> `Дополнительно` --> `Изменить язык системы` 
Выбираем русский язык и ставим галочку на "Использовать Unicode UTF-8" 
Сохраняем, перезагружаем, profit.

Comment: Если сделать как описано выше: Пуск --> Settings --> Время и язык --> Регион --> Дополнительные параметры(справа) --> Региональные стандарты --> Дополнительно --> Изменить язык системы --> Выбираем русский язык и ставим галочку на "Использовать Unicode UTF-8" То вы избавитесь от проблем с кодировкой в Atom, но у Вас могут появится проблемы с кодировкой в других программах. Так что решайте сами, что Вам важно, кодировка в Atom или проблемы с кодировкой в др. приложениях. Как по мне, лучше для кодинга, использовать Visual Studio Code, и никаких проблем с кодировками не будет.